# how can i fetch the value of name in type field in mongoose using nodejs

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

Data:

```
const data = {
  "name": "folded carton",
  "types": [
    {
      "name": "Reverse Tuck End",
      "subname": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "tuck end auto bottom",
      "subname": "(Bottom Pesting)"
    },
    {
      "name": "tuck end lock bottom",
      "subname": "(lock bottom)"
    }]
}
```

Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const product_category_Schema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  types: [{ name: String, subname: String }],
});

product_category = mongoose.model("category", product_category_Schema);

module.exports = product_category;
```

Comment: Hi, Himanshu can you tell me how you want the output to look i.e you just want the array of name values or something? Kindly include that as well for clarity

Comment: get the value of name : `data.types.map(e=>e.name)`, use that in your page, `data.types.map(e=><li>{e.name}</li>)` or what you need make it